# Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userSevice';

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

When im trying to run my spring project im getting error, may be the problem is in the dependecies idk, also there is almost the same problem with userService bean.

Error text:

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userSevice'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'shop.repos.UserRepo' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

My WebSecurityConfig

```
package shop.config;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import shop.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="java", entityManagerFactoryRef="emf")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private UserService userSevice;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/",
                        "/registration",
                        "/registrationClientInfo").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userSevice)
                .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
    }
}
```

My Application.java

```
package shop;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>MarchenkoKohovich</groupId>
    <artifactId>Shop</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--security-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My appclication.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/electronic?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=88fo
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

spring.freemarker.expose-request-attributes=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

ALSO:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'shop.repos.UserRepo' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

UserService.java

```
package shop.service;

import shop.entity.User;
import shop.repos.UserRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;


@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepo.findByUsername(username);
    }

    @Transactional
    public Iterable<User> loadAllUsers(){
        return userRepo.findAll();
    }

    @Transactional
    public User saveUsers(User user){
        return userRepo.save(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void deleteUser(User user){
        userRepo.delete(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<User> loadUserByActive(boolean active){
        return  userRepo.findByActive(active);
    }

}
```

UserRepo.java

```
package shop.repos;

import shop.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
    List<User> findByActive(boolean active);
}
```

Comment: Try registering your repository by adding @Repository annotation on the repository class

Comment: nothing changed :(

Answer (score 2):

You have problem with annotation:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="java", entityManagerFactoryRef="emf")
```

You try to scan your annotated entities in package called "java", but it can be seen from your config file that actual package starts from "shop".

You should change your annotation to this:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="shop.repos", entityManagerFactoryRef="emf")
```

Comment: oh sure, thx for the tip. but unfortunately, is not the problem solution

Comment: Actually, you are using spring boot. You don't need this annotation @EnableJpaRepositories. Spring boot will autoconfigure for you all this stuff because you have spring-boot-starter-data-jpa in your maven dependecies. Try to remove this annotation and all hibernate dependencies: core and entityManager. You don't need them if you use jpa repositories.

Comment: All those deppendencies was added to solve other problem and after deleting that, i had this problem again, Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister

Comment: I even not using this "entityManagerFactory", idk why it appear and ruin my program (

Comment: I have similar with your project: https://github.com/dmcheremisin/SpringHibernate/tree/master/chapter54springboot
please, check it.

Comment: i tooked emf bean and added it to config, and after that problems which are described in my question returned to their place back.

Answer (score 0):

Let me play Captain Obvious: the problem is that Spring can't find any bean for `UserRepo`:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'shop.repos.UserRepo' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate
```

Could you show the code for `UserRepo` ?

Comment: sure, i add it to the question

Answer (score 0):

You haven't registered UserRepo with the spring container

Comment: please look, i add it to the question's decription

Answer (score 0):

You need a bean of type UserRepo, so create something like:

```
interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long>
```

Comment: i've got one, like, package shop.repos;

import shop.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
    List<User> findByActive(boolean active);
}

Comment: In you User class do you have an id from type long and annotation on the class Entity? It should be something like:

@Entity
public class User {

    @ Id
    private Long id;